# Find Last occurrence index value of inner list and outer list in efficient way in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey i have nested list and i wanted to find last occurrence index value of inner list and outer list. I tried to search [Find last occurrence of a String in array using Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138413/find-last-occurrence-of-a-string-in-array-using-kotlin/46138435).
How can I do this in my case in efficient way.

**Group**

```
data class Group(
    val key: Int,
    val value: MutableList<GroupValue?>
)
```

**GroupValue**

```
data class GroupValue(
    val isRead: Boolean? = null,
    val id: String? = null
)
```

**Condition**

```
isRead != true
```

**For example**

**Scenario 1**

```
 val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
    )
```

**Excepted output**

```
inner list index is 0 and outer list index is 4
```

**Scenario 2**

```
val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
        Group(6, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"),GroupValue(false, "7"))),
        Group(7, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "7")))
    )
```

**Excepted output**

```
inner list index is 1 and outer list index is 6
```

Inside this [Find first occurrence index value in efficient way in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614737/find-first-occurrence-index-value-in-efficent-way-in-kotlin/69615464?noredirect=1#comment123053675_69615464) I asked for first index but now I need in last occurrence .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOfLast` and `indexOfFirst` functions for this

```
var innerIndex = -1
val outerIndex: Int = value.indexOfLast{ group ->
    innerIndex = group.value.indexOfFirst { groupValue -> groupValue != null && groupValue.isRead != true }
    return@indexOfLast innerIndex != -1
}

if(outerIndex != -1) {
    // match found 
}
```

Comment: great answer thanks a million..

Comment: can you add code to find innerIndex and outerIndex separately?

Comment: above code is finding both at a time can you separate code as well